# Is it possible to just make like once you hover your mouse over a navigation button in a navbar, it shows the description of it?

Tags: html, css

When I hover my mouse on a navigation icon in the navigation bar, I want it to simply expand and show what the icon refers to.

[image: Example icons]

For example, if I hover my mouse over the Facebook icon, it should shows a description as in a different navigation button saying "Facebook Page" and once I move my mouse away, it goes away.

I'm pretty new to this, I'd appreciate any help.

Current CSS:

```css
.showfacebook {
  display: none;
}

.showbook {
  display: none;
}

.showpen {
  display: none;
}

.showusergraduate {
  display: none;
}

.showusergroup {
  display: none;
}

.showfacebook a:hover {
  display: block;
}

.showbook a:hover {
  display: block;
}

.showpen a:hover {
  display: block;
}

.showusergraduate a:hover {
  display: block;
}

.showusergroup a:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the [CSS Tooltip](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp)? If you want to change the image itself into something else like text then you'll need JavaScript

Comment: Not exactly like that, but I mean, I've seen a similar post about it somewhere here but I lost it, however, it is supposed to like show the text that describes the icon in a different navigation box button but it only shows it when the mouse is hovered over the icon, if you move it away, it goes away.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).